# Extraer caracteres de campo varchar SQL SERVER

Tags: sql

Necesito extraer los seis primeros caracteres de la cuenta contable la cual esta almacenada en un campo VARCHAR(200). Al ejecutar la consulta trae seis caracteres pero inserta una coma. Necesito los caracteres sin la coma.[image: ResultadoConsulta]

Comment: qué motor de base de datos estás usando?, me imagino que la coma viene en el dato de origen?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008 R2 X 64

Comment: No veo una coma, más bien parece un punto, que por otro lado es un caracter habitual en los código de cuentas, ¿que es lo que buscas al intentar quitar este caracter de esta columna?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, tiene razón, soy algo ciego, Muchas gracias.Por ejemplo para la cuenta 100105001 necesito extraer los seis primeros caracteres, es decir, 100105.

Comment: En ese caso el `LEFT(GLAccount, 6)`  es lo que buscas

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes solucionar con un simple `REPLACE` para eliminar la coma dentro del `LEFT`.

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(GLAccount, ',', ''), 6) AS Cuenta
FROM T_GLAccount
```

Comment: Mejoro mucho, pero arroja resultados como en notación científica ejemplo: 16e+00 o 11051e

Comment: Eso es porque estás convirtiendolos a tipo float. Si son cuentas contables, deben permanecer como varchar.

Comment: @Roger Torne. Muchas gracias por la oportunidad de aprender de ustedes.